# Page through dataset without getting new dataset in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, paging, pagedlist

I have 3 different functions on my page.  1.) Search, 2.) Sort and 3.) Paging

I have all of this working, but I was wondering if anyone know how, or can point me somewhere that shows how to save, per user, the dataset so they can sort and page without searching again and then also when the user Searches to pull the data again.

I'm currently using MVC5, Bootstrap, and PagedList.MVC

Here's an example of what I need.  I honestly am not sure how to or even if I should cache the data, but it seems like I would want to as this data changes regularly (they are events from a DB) and I'd like the user to work with the dataset they searched and not with a new dataset every time they page or sort.

```
private List<Models.EventItem> events = null;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewLogs(ViewModels.ViewLogs model)
{
    if (model.ActionPerformed == "search")
    {
        // it was a search, so let's pull new events in.
        events = Business.Events.GetEvents(GetCurrentSearchParameters(model));
    }

    if (model.ActionPerformed == "sort")
    {
        events = null // need to grab events from the cached dataset?
        // then need to perform the sort on the cached dataset.
    } 

    if (model.ActionPerformed == "page")
    {
        events = null // need to grab events from the cached dataset?
    }

    model.EventItems = events.ToPagedList(model.CurrentPage, model.PageSize);
    return View("ViewLogs", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewLogs()
{
    // ViewLogs (Get) will take defaults instead.
    ViewModels.ViewLogs model = new ViewModels.ViewLogs();

    events = Business.Events.GetEvents(GetCurrentSearchParameters(model));
    model.EventItems = events.ToPagedList(model.CurrentPage, model.PageSize);

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: you can perform all these operations by accessing `dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView`

Comment: Look at the article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69c06922(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Sorry maybe wasn't clear.  I initially call ViewLogs() and show the data.  Then they post either a sort, page, or search and it calls ViewLogs(model) and the data I had is no longer there.  The only way for me to retrieve it is to call the dataset again.  I'm looking for a way to keep the data between postbacks.

Comment: The only way to pass data from one page to another page or between postbacks is to make use of `TempData` or `Hidden` fields

Comment: you can also make use of `Session` but i'm not sure why you don't prefer it?

Comment: This defeats the entire point of paging. The goal is to reduce the amount of data that must be queried at any one time by only showing a portion of the results at once. If you're going to just pull everything, you might as well show everything as well.

Comment: You are right about Session.  Not sure how I forgot about that.  I don't think I can load an entire dataset (or maybe don't want to) in a Hidden field and TempData as I understand it, it only from Controller to View or View to Controller, right?  Pretty sure I tried that and when I posted back, it was null.

Comment: I kind of agree @ChrisPratt , hence why I was asking...  All of the paging tutorials show to pass in the whole dataset with what page number and it was bothering me.

Comment: The basic way of using PagedList is to pass the whole *unevaluated* dataset. Until you do something atomic like iterate or cast to a list, no queries have actually been issued. PagedList, then, adds the appropriate skip and take arguments to limit it to just the current page. If you are querying the entire dataset from the database first (such as by calling `ToList()` on it, first, before passing it on to PagedList), then you're doing it wrong. If you need to evaluate the query first for some reason (such as mapping to a view model), you are responsible for limiting the results, first.

Comment: In that scenario, you can then use `StaticPagedList` to create a pageable queryset that's already been limited.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under my question, you can go about this 2 ways.  The not-so-great way, but works is using Session to save the data and conditionally populate it.

What I've done research on is to actually use SQL to do the paging.  In SQL you set something up similar to this which will give you total row count, total page count, and then whatever page worth of data.  From what I understand, especially dealing with large chunks of data, this can save a *massive* amount of time.  Thanks to all for putting me on the right track.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @fromDate DATETIME = DATEADD(d, -30, GETUTCDATE()) 
DECLARE @page INT = 1
DECLARE @perPage INT = 25
DECLARE @totalRows INT = 0
DECLARE @totalPages INT = 0
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
   --
   SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(*)
   FROM 
          dbo.[Events] a
   WHERE
          a.[EventTime] >= @fromDate
   ;
   --
   BEGIN TRY
          SET @totalPages = CEILING(@totalRows / @perPage); 
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
          SET @totalPages = 0
   END CATCH
   --
   SELECT @totalRows AS [TotalRows], @totalPages AS [TotalPages];
   --
   --
   SELECT
          a.[EventTime],
          a.[Column1],
          a.[Column2]
   FROM 
          dbo.[Events] a
   WHERE
          a.[EventTime] >= @fromDate
   ORDER BY 
          a.[EventTime] DESC
          OFFSET (@page * @perPage) ROWS
          FETCH NEXT @perPage ROWS ONLY
   ;
END
```

There's a pretty in-depth article on it here: http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch